# Tkinter .tkrise() and .lift() does nothing

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to make any app with two windows, first one for choosing parameters and second for displaying.

This is how my attemp was looking so far

```
class MainFrame(tk.Tk):
    """ This is main class for managing different views(windows) """
    def onClosing(self):
        self.manager.stopMainLoop()
        self.destroy()
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------     
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        # init main frame
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        # init dict for storing avaliable frames
        self.frames = {}

        # init frame add to dict
        frame = StartFrame.StartFrame(container, self)
        self.frames[StartFrame] = frame

        # init frame add to dict
        frame = CanvasFrame.CanvasFrame(container, self)
        self.frames[CanvasFrame] = frame

        # add close window event handler
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.onClosing)
        # load canvas as first
        self.show_frame(CanvasFrame)
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
    def show_frame(self, cont):
        """ makes choosen frame visibale at top"""
        # get window
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        # .lift() should also works
        # make window in front
        frame.tkraise()
        # set gird position
        frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nwse")
```

This is StartFrame init code

```
    class StartFrame(tk.Frame):
    """ This is main class for starting different windows based on choosen options"""
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------     
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        # init main frame
        self.controller = controller
        container = tk.Frame(self, width=500, height=300)
#         container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        # stores starting options
        self.checkBoxDict = dict()

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        # add start info
        entryInfo = tk.Label(text = "Choose your settings, one window running different algorithm will be open for every check box checked")
        # columnspan is used to allow components be better spaced between each other
        entryInfo.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan=10)
        # add rest of controlers
        self.addControlers()
```

This is CanvasFrame init code

```
    class CanvasFrame(tk.Frame):
    """ This is main class for managing displaying visual changes to a path"""
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------     
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.rootWindow = controller
        wid = 800
        hei = 400
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width = wid, height = hei)
        self.canvas.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 10,sticky = "nswe")
```

Also in StartFrame is a button that invoke this method from MainFrame

```
self.controller.show_frame(CanvasFrame)
```

After button is clicked method invoks but nothing is happaning after tkraise method is done

There are two main issues

1.) Even thought on init of MainFrame choosen frame to be raisen is CanvasFrame StartFrame is on top

2.) When button on StartFrame is clicked and invoks without any error MainFrame.frame(cont) method, nothing is rising

***Update***

I have add this change and it started open new window but how i can switch frames on top of main window ?

```
    d

class CanvasFrame(tk.Toplevel):
    """ This is main class for managing displaying visual changes to a path"""
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------     
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        self.rootWindow = controller
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self,parent)
```

Comment: Rethink your GUI design, to many `Frame` over `Frame` over `Canvas`. Keep in mind `MainFrame(tk.Tk)` is a `Frame`. Your mistake are, you don't `container.grid(...`, therefore all following Frames are hidden.

Comment: i removed `container.grid` but still the behavior is the same, can you make example for a good design ? I am using one from [sentdex](https://pythonprogramming.net/object-oriented-programming-crash-course-tkinter/) but it is not working well for me

Comment: *" still the behavior is the same"*: [Edit] your Question and show your attemp, show only `MainFrame.__init__(...` without comments. Removing `container = tk.Frame(self)` and it works as expected.

Comment: I do not excatly understand what do you want me to try

Comment: I have change evertying to be packed not grid and now two windows shows up in one root window